# This does not appear to be a WXR file, missing/invalid WXR version number

Tags: wordpress, import, zip

I'm trying to import posts from medium to WordPress.

[https://upthemes.com/blog/2014/11/medium-to-wordpress/][1]

I followed this blog
I downloaded a zip file. and when I try to import it using WordPress importer as mentioned in the blog.
It throws an error`'This does not appear to be a WXR file, missing/invalid WXR version number'`.

The default plugin as given by WordPress **'WordPress Importer'** doesn't have an XML file and I'm not able to change WXR version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export zip file and upload just xml file with WordPress Importer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS ec2 then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php-xml
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: this sorted my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the proper XML file that was exported from WordPress. Otherwise, it will show errors. The first thing you should do is to export the XML file from WordPress like in the image. Then you can upload the XML file. Problem solved.

Error is that the WRX file is missing. This is because the WRX file contains only if it is properly exported. Enjoy!

[image: Exporting image]